# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement portaudio (from versions: none)

Tags: windows, pip, windows-11, portaudio

```
C:\Users\91938\Desktop> pip3 install portaudio
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement portaudio (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for portaudio
```

this error is showing when I try to install portaudio package

I  am trying to install the portaudio package